# How to create UILabel in IOS with only code?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I know how to customize a UILabel that is already on the main storyboard, but it there a way to size and position a UILabel with only code?

Comment: Of course this can be done. What have you attempted so far? What issue are you having?

Comment: I have not attempted anything yet. I do not even know where to begin. Do I start with UILabel *firstLabel;

Comment: Have you searched for other questions similar to yours? I can't imagine there not being one out there already.

Comment: I am looking and cannot find anything for ios7

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

```
CGFloat x,y, width, height;
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
myLabel.text = @"foo";
//Now add it to your view hierarchy
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

I hope this helps. 
I highly recommend you to go through this [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do to customise storyboard `UILabel`

```
// Create IBOutlet to get UILabel object in your view controller .m file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel        *storyboardLabel;

// Go to storyboard and link this label to your storyboard label of this view controller
```

Then place below code where you want to reposition or resize your `UILabel`.

```
// Get rect (position & size) of storyboard label
CGRect rect = self.storyboardLabel.frame;
rect.origin.x = 100; // Your preferable left position
rect.origin.y = 100; // Your preferable top position
rect.size.width = 200; // Your preferable label width
rect.size.height = 20; // Your preferable label height
[self.storyboardLabel setFrame:rect];
```